# Request failed with http status 403 forbidden -Webservice-while calling the service via iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

Iam a beginer in c# .currently iam working on a api in which the request AND response are working properly(Visual studio)
But when it was published in the same pc's iis(iis 7)  one error is getting AS " the request failed with http status 403 forbidden"
.Api uses ssl certificate also. 
Whats wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what user is being used for the service and whether that user is being allowed authentication.  You left out a lot details out about your IIS configuration.   Out of the box, IIS rarely serves ASPX without some adjustments.